# 'HOST' is not recognized as an internal command

Tags: reactjs, git, visual-studio

I'm trying to start a project that I cloned from github, the repo is: 
https://10-142-4-182-4000.hackerrank.io/git-ag2igctgjqp/10gp4j0bs5s react--login-portal-10gp4j0bs5s

It's a verification code for react, but using the Hacker Rank's IDE is not helping me, as I can not use the console or debugger.

When starting the server, I get this error:

```
25 error code ELIFECYCLE
26 error errno 1
27 error login-portal@0.1.0 start: `HOST=0.0.0.0 PORT=8000 ./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts start`
27 error Exit status 1
```

Comment: The link you posted doesn't work and what is the `react--login-portal-10gp4j0bs5s` bit? That isn't a valid URL

Comment: The URL you provided is not a GitHub endpoint.  We can be helpful if you provide more detailed information.  Assuming you cloned the project correctly, the error you showed is really NOT a git problem.  It appears to be related directly to the project you cloned.

Comment: I fixed it by removing "HOST=0.0.0.0 PORT=8000"